# Get Volume of Arbirtrary frame in Clip (Java)?

Tags: java, audio, clip

I've been trying to get the volume of a specific frame of a Clip in Java. If it matters, it's in the WAV file format.
I tried the following, assuming `clip` is a `Clip` object and `i` is an arbitrary `int`. All I get is -1.0, which is equivalent to `AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFICED`

```
if(clip.isOpen())
{
    clip.setFramePosition(i);
    System.out.println(clip.getLevel());
}
```

I checked the clip has been loaded by playing it, which worked. Can anyone help me figure this out? 
The code this snippet is from:

```
AudioInputStream ais;
Clip clip;
int i = 6; //Arbitrary value
ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\Arbitrary\Path\File.wav"));
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
if(clip.isOpen())
{
    clip.setFramePosition(i);
    float level = clip.getLevel();
    System.out.println(level);
}
```

Comment: You marked your question as JavaFX, but you aren't using JavaFX.  If you were, maybe you could add an [AudioSpectrumListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#audioSpectrumListenerProperty) to your MediaPlayer to receive [spectrumDataUpdates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioSpectrumListener.html#spectrumDataUpdate-double-double-float:A-float:A-) of the decibel magnitudes at various frequencies for the audio track at various moments in time.

Comment: Sorry, removed incorrect tag.